# find the first cell in range where cumulative sum >= 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have an excel file like this:
[image]

could anyone help me to find the first cell (from left to right) so that cumulative sum >=0

[demo file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TJtThB-yhd-e_Hk6X_VrgIHSZchaHJM9EGhBNqXrqRU/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ms365 try:

[image]

Formula in `C6`:

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,SCAN(0,C2:J2,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))>=0,C2:J2,"No value >= 0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Or prior Excel versions:

```
=INDEX(C1:J1,MATCH(TRUE,(MMULT(--(COLUMN(C1:J1)<=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C1:J1))),TRANSPOSE(C1:J1)))>=0,0))
```

(May require entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`)

Comment: You can save a `TRANSPOSE` if you write it this way round: `=INDEX(C1:J1,MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(C1:J1,N(COLUMN(C1:J1)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C1:J1))))>=0,0))`

Comment: True (and this was inspired by your answer earlier this week).